# Open image link as lightbox within prettyphoto inline overlay

Tags: prettyphoto

I have text and a an image opening as a Prettyphoto inline overlay. But when the image link within is clicked it opens new tab image link.

Is there anyway to have it open another prettyphoto overlay on top?
So when the image is closed the other inline overlay is still open?

Answer (score 0):

The way I figured it out was by having a different lightbox plugin automatically add rel=lightbox to all img file types. This made it override prettyPhoto (which I coded to use class="prettyPhoto-link" instead of a rel

In function.php

```
  add_filter('the_content', 'chosted_image_attribute');

function chosted_image_attribute($content) {
       global $post;
       $pattern ="/<a(.*?)href=('|\")(.*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)('|\")(.*?)>/i";
       $replacement = '<a$1href=$2$3.$4$5 rel="lightbox">';
       $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
       return $content;
}
```

And this is at the top of jquery.prettyPhoto.js

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".prettyphoto-link").prettyPhoto({
            animation_speed:'normal',
            allow_resize: true,
            keyboard_shortcuts: true,
            show_title: false,
            social_tools: false,
            autoplay_slideshow: false
        });
    });
});
```

This can help you call pretty photo from PHP code, since sometimes rel doesnt work.